# Get <div> to resize when users resizes browser

Tags: css, browser, html, scroll, resize

I want a div's width and height to change with the browser as the browser's width and height are changed when a user changes their browses dimensions.

Code added based on the answers suggestion

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"> 
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
    <title>Some Company - Terms and Conditions</title>
</head>
<body >
<div>
    some anchor links here go to the content inside the div below
    </div>
   <div style="position: absolute; top: 100; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;overflow:auto;padding:10px;border:1px solid lightblue;">
     content here
    </div>
</body>
```

Here was the end result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Terms and Conditions</title></head>
<body>
<a href="#tac20">Terms and Conditions 20</a> | <a href="#tac40">Terms and Conditions 40</a>

    <div style="position:absolute; top: 30px; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;overflow-y:auto;padding:5px;border-top:1px solid lightblue;">
        Terms and Condition 1 <br/>     
        Terms and Condition 2 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 3 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 4 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 5 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 6 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 7 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 8 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 9 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 10 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 11 <br/>        
        Terms and Condition 12 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 13 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 14 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 15 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 16 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 17 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 18 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 19 <br/>
        <a name="tac20">Terms and Condition 20</name> <br/>
        Terms and Condition 21 <br/>        
        Terms and Condition 22 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 23 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 24 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 25 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 26 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 27 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 28 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 29 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 30 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 31 <br/>        
        Terms and Condition 32 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 33 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 34 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 35 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 36 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 37 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 38 <br/>
        Terms and Condition 39 <br/>
        <a name="tac40">Terms and Condition 40</name> <br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: -1 Because 80% of the question is irrelevant details (aka rambling) and in the end I still have no clue what you are asking

Comment: my bad, had a few beers. I will change it in 30 secs.

Comment: can you not just use percentages for the CSS width/height attributes as opposed to pixels?

Comment: thanks for the comment, height set to a percentage will not produce this effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right solution depends on the layout of the page.  If you just have a single `div` you want to fill the browser window, I find this CSS the easiest solution:

```
#theDiv { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }
```

Comment: You took the words out of my mouth. This method also allows you to add a consistent gap around the div. Sizing in percentages will fluctuate the size of the gap around the div.

Comment: Yeah it looks good and works too! Check my edit to see what's going on

Comment: I have links above that I always want to be on top for nav